# Trying to determine if I can create a calculated column to do math based on specific text

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I have been looking over many formulas and ways to do calculated columns in SharePoint. I had some success in Excel but just can't seem to get it to work OTOB in SharePoint. My goal is to Calculate a percentage complete as a result of what text is in 2 columns. One column is a managers name and the other is a dropdown status of (Initial, Scheduled, Complete) I want to determine percent complete by manager name by comparing the name with the status and totaling each status. Then using the numeric totals to calculate the percentage complete by manager. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you might want to add screenshot. if I understand your requirement correctly, you are trying to look into another item from calculated column, which is not possible. You can only access data from same row

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS code to get your desired output by taking reference from below given page.

[JavaScript and HTML in SharePoint Calculated Columns](http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How)

Danny from Viewmaster has a great page on HTML Calculated Columns and Javascript!

You need to write down your own logic to achieve this. If you need anything then kindly provide some more details.

**Note:-** Microsoft have disabled HTML/JS injecting using this Calculated Column trick for Modern Experience site. So this solution will only work on 2007 till 2016/SP Online in CLASSIC mode.

Comment: Have you tried it? Is that working for you? Kindly let me know if not/any query